# API request Coldfusion (GET request)

Tags: api, coldfusion, httprequest

I am trying to build a HTTP request to an external API to get some data. Actually first request will be to get an authorization token which will be used on the second HTTP request to get the data needed.
I have tried eveything without any luck and this is the first time building an request to an API. 
I was given this example request:

```
POST https://api2-test.com/Identity/v1/Token HTTP/1.1
Host: api2-test.com 
Accept: application/json 
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

userName=my.account%40mydomain.com&password=MyPassword&grant_type=password
```

I am using ColdFusion to build this and any help would be really appreciated.

**EDIT:**
This is what I have been trying but it is not working:

```
<cfhttp url="https://api2-test.com/Identity/v1/Token HTTP/1.1" password="test" username="test2" result="object">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/json">
</cfhttp>
```

EDIT 2: I was able to successfully get the data from the API but can't use the results. It is saying it is not a JSON object!

```
<cfhttp url="#apiURL#" method="get" result="httpResp" timeout="120">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/json" />
    <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="method" value="test">
</cfhttp>
[![screen shot of the results][1]][1]<cfdump var="#httpResp#" />
```

I don't know why the picture is showing weird but here is the filecontent :

```
{"access_token":"<TokenIsHere>","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":259199,"userName":"my.account@mydomain.com","issued":"Tue, 23 May 2017 00:53:39 AD5T","expires":"Fri, 26 May 2017 00:53:39 AD5T"}
```

it also says: wddx encoded

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: All I done so far is just playing around with <cfhttp> tag but no luck with any of it. The purpose of this post is just to help me build a valid request and then probably just dump the results on the page because I can take it from there how to work with that JSON object.

Comment: We can’t do it for you. You will need to post your code so we can tell you where you’re going wrong. Google cfhttp docs will give you the basics of a http request.

Comment: you need `cfhttpparam type="formfield"` for all the values you see in the body of the sample request: i.e. userName, password and grant_type

Comment: Without knowing anything else, you probably need to `DeserializeJSON() ` the `content` property of the results.

Comment: @snackboy that is what I though too but I tried running DeserializeJSON() and got the following error:
"message": "JSON parsing failure at character 1:'<' in <wddxPacket version='1.0'><header/><data><string>{"access_token":"TokenIsHere","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":259199,"userName":"my.account@mydomain.com","issued":"Tue, 23 May 2017 00:53:39 AD5T","expires":"Fri, 26 May 2017 00:53:39 AD5T"}</string></data></wddxPacket>"
However when I validate the results from the GET request (filecontent) it is saying VALID JSON.

Comment: I think you have to do something like `<cfset _return = deserializeJSON(cfhttp.filecontent)>`.  At least that's been my experience.

Comment: You guys are correct, I need to deserializeJSON(httpResp.filecontent). I tried cfhttp.filecontent but it didn't work. httpResp is the result attribute on my original request.
Thank you everyone.

Comment: @DoArNa, wonderful! I should've picked up on the result variable being used. Normally I don't, so the results are returned as cfhttp.

Comment: @snackboy oh I didn't know that if you don't use an attribute "result" it will default to cfhttp. Learned a new thing. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the JSON response from an api request, you need to use deserializeJSON(cfhttp.fileContent) which will return a coldfusion structure. You can use cfdump to verify it.